# How to Target HTML Elements of the Bootstrap Navbar (v4.5) for Custom Styling with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, target

I am having difficulty figuring out the method for targeting elements of the Bootstrap Navbar (v4.5) with CSS.  I would like a **method**, if possible, for determining proper target paths. For example with the following HTML navbar how would I target the **navbar-brand** and the **nav-link**:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-custom">
  <!-- targetting the navbar-brand below -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food, LLC</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

      <!-- Three items in drop down menu: Chicken, Beef, Sushi-->
      <li class="nav-item active">
   <!-- targetting the nav-link below -->
        <a class="nav-link" id="blob" href="#">Chicken<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="blob" href="#">Beef</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sushi</a>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
    
  </div>

</nav>
```

In the above HTML lets say I wanted to style the navbar-brand and the first nav-link. Let's also assume I do not want to insert ID's to accomplish this but would rather use other methods to target those elements in the CSS.

All I have come up with so far is to use the browser inspection which will show a path in the SCSS file (example given below).  Those given paths are very long and obtuse. There must be a more direct way to target simple elements of a navbar.

For example, here is the path for targeting the first nav-link as given by the broswer inspection tool:

".navbar-light .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active "

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to *target* those elements ? Browser inspection is a very good way to see what rules are applied, and to try some css overriding.

However, I do not recommand you to modify directly the bootstrap code, you should create your own scss files, import needed bootstrap scss files [as described here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/), then deliver your customized css with override rules.

### For example : _common.scss

```
/**
This file act as a loader for each styles which are common through the site
*/
@import 'custom_variables';
@import 'custom_mixins';
@import 'custom_bootstrap';
@import 'forms';

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, Roboto, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#sidebar-brand-logo {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: $white;
}

.sidebar {
  .sidebar-heading {
    font-size: .9rem;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
  }
}

.bg-brand {
  background-color: $brand-primary;
  color: $white;

  &.sidebar-dark {
    .nav-item {
      .nav-link {
        i, span {
          color: $white;
        }

        i {
          font-size: 1rem;
        }

        span {
          font-weight: 400;
          font-style: italic;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

.bg-brand-light {
  background-color: lighten($brand-primary, 25%);
  color: $white;
}

.bg-brand-secondary {
  background-color: $brand-secondary;
  color: $white;
}

button, a {
  &.bg-brand:hover {
    background-color: lighten($brand-primary, 25%);
    color: $white;
  }

  &.bg-brand-light:hover {
    background-color: $brand-primary;
    color: $white;
  }

  &.bg-brand-secondary:hover {
    background-color: darken($brand-secondary, 10%);
    color: $white;
  }
}

.radius0 {
  border-radius: unset;
}

a.dropdown-item:not([href]) {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: fade_out($dropdown-link-color, 0.75) !important;
}

.display-grid{
  display: grid;
}

.card-body ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

In my `_custom_bootstrap.scss`, I'm importing only the bootstrap components and behavior I want to reduce the produced css for each pages of my site.

Don't forget that [Sass has `nested rules`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules#nesting) which are converted to css.

So your example :
`.navbar-light .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active` is equivalent to **scss** below (it is an example) :

```
.navbar-light{
    // Some styling rules for the navbar
    .navbar-nav{
        // Some styling rules for .navbar-nav wrapped by .navbar-light
        .show, .active{
        // Some styling rules for items with show or active class
            & > .nav-link{
            // Some styling rules for .nav-link wrapped by .navbar-nav within .navbar-light with show or active
            }
        }
        .nav-link{
        // Some styling rules for .nav-link wrapped by .navbar-nav which is wrapped .navbar-light
            &.show, &.active{
            // Some styling rules for ... .nav-link WITH show or active classes 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, you can override those rules with or without nested rules, and apply your style

```
.nav-link{
    color:blue;
}
```

But it depends if you want to apply the rule for each elements, with or without wrapper *parent*.